# Can't Connect Filebeat to Kafla via SASL_SSL

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

Really stuck with the issue. Having kafka output in filebeat as below:

```
output.kafka:
  # initial brokers for reading cluster metadata
  hosts: ["kafka:19095"]

  # message topic selection + partitioning
  topic: "test-topic"
  sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
  ssl.enabled: true
  ssl.certificate_authorities: C:\config\kafka.pem
  username: test-user
  password: test-password
```

Kafka is running in Docker and SASL_SSL port is exposed to host (19095). I can connect from other tools without any problem.
However, for Filebeat I see the following error in Kafka logs:

`[2023-09-15 17:17:16,434] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /172.28.0.1 (channelId=172.28.0.5:19095-172.28.0.1:56608-128) (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)`

In Filebeat logs:
`{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-15T20:21:16.339+0300","log.logger":"kafka","log.origin":{"file.name":"kafka/client.go","file.line":337},"message":"Kafka (topic=test-topiconnecc): kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}`

I.e. the reason of SSL handshake failure is absolutely unclear. Cert is self signed and uses "kafka" as a subject which matches host - so this is not the issue..

Does anyone have any possible ideas? Really stuck with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try wrapping the path in single quotation marks? (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.6/yaml-tips.html#wrap-paths-in-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in self-signed certificate that didn't use SAN.
So setting "ssl.verification_mode" to "certificate" helped.